# Android emulator camera custom image through command line

Tags: android, automation, android-emulator

I was able to update the wall and table custom images of an emulator when its up through the UI as the following images, my question is, is there any way to do the same steps through an API or even a command for automation testing purposes?

[UI steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bU3LH.png)